# how to add string date coming from xml to nsarray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have some string date which is coming from xml RSS feed. what I want to do is to add these string into nsarray. the code is

```
NSString *headline=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"title"];
```

now i want to store this string into nsarray. as i am implementing searchbar in uitableview
can anybody help me please.

Thanks in advance

hey guys I have done it the code is

```
NSArray *theArray = [headline componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

To store the one string, you would want:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:headline];
```

To store more than one object:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrrayWithObjects:headline, object2, nil];
```

(The last object passed to this function must always have a nil argument after it.)

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for replying em trying to implement your code...

Thanks

Comment: The correct code is 

NSArray *theArray = [headline componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Comment: haha. Well, that doesn't have anything to do with your question. You didn't say that you were trying to split the string or even that the string was separated by commas. You merely asked how to store a NSString in a NSArray.